# How to create VHDL package with component and no package body?

Tags: vhdl, quartus

In Quartus 16.0, I have a `foo.vhd` and `bar.vhd` files, each containing a valid/working entity and corresponding architecture. I am trying to create a package with `foo` and `bar` in it. I have something like this:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

package my_package is

    component foo
            port(
                a, b : in  std_logic;
                out : out std_logic);
    end component;

    component bar
            port(
                a, b : in  std_logic;
                out : out std_logic);
    end component;

end package my_package;
```

Trying to compile it, I receive the error: `Error (12007): Top-level design entity "my_package" is undefined`. I am not sure where the problem is and as a beginner don't yet know how to go about debugging it.

Comment: `out` is a reserved word in all revisions of the VHDL standard and may not be used as a name of a declared interface object (e.g. `out : out std_logic`). Changing both to `output` and `my_package` successfully analyzes. This says you're trying to synthesize before simulation and your tool is not fully compliant with the standard.  A reserved word is recognized as a lexical element. IEEE Std 1076-2008 15.10 Reserved words paragraph 3 *A reserved word shall not be used as an explicitly declared identifier.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually using a package as the top level of your design. Those two things are different. A package stores useful constants, functions, etc... whereas the top level (which is an entity) instantiates and map components between each other. Take a look at this link to see how to implement a top level entity :

https://www.altera.com/support/support-resources/design-examples/design-software/vhdl/v_hier.html

In VHDL you don't need to add your entity (or component) in a package. You just need to compile them in the same library - usually `WORK`.

When compiling your top level entity, which instantiate all the components your design need, Quartus looks for the vhdl file containing the entity called by the instantiation.

Comment: Thanks! I was setting package as top level without thinking what I was doing. In my case `use work.my_package.foo` or `use work.my_package.bar` works on actual top level.